# in eclipse,i tried to open "window" in the tool bar and it is not working. what do i do?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

in eclipse ,i accidentally minimized the console . so tried to open the "window" option which is next to the run option in the tool bar. "window" option is not getting opened.none of those options are working !not able to figure out the problem !

Comment: Restart maybe? Your eclipse, your system!

Comment: How about [ResetPerspective] (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9j.htm)

Comment: 'Window' > 'Reset Perspective' should work. Not really a programming question though.

Comment: i am not able to open the "window" option !none of those options are working.

Comment: The shortcut is `Shift+Alt+Q`, which will open a popup window where you should see that `C` should show the console. If that doesn't bring the console to view, reinstall eclipse I guess.

Comment: ah not working.! i will have to reinstall eclipse

Comment: the same problem in my laptop.the tool bar which has  file,edit,refactor,....
none of these can be opened.
installation was fine.

Comment: On which OS did that happen ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem on Ubuntu 13.10. None of the menus of eclipse were working, even after restart (of both OS and eclipse).

To resolve this, I ended up installing the gnome-fallback-session package as described in the link below:
[How To Install Gnome Classic](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gnome-classic-gnome-fallback-on-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-12-10-12-04/)